# Content Security Policy nodejs usando fetch

Tags: nodejs, express, csp

soy nuevo usando nodejs y estoy con el problema Content Security Policy cuando hago un fetch post hacia una ruta.
Intente usando helmet y cors pero sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje en la consola:
"Content Security Policy: Las opciones para esta página han bloqueado la carga de un recurso en http://localhost:8080/ (default-src)."

mi codigo:

index.js

```
   const express = require('express')
   const helmet = require("helmet")
   var cors = require('cors');
   const app = express()
   const port = 8080

   app.use(helmet());
   app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));

   app.post('/', (request, response) => {
      response.send(request);
   });

   app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('something bad happened', err)
   }

    console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
   })

´´´
// el codigo que uso en la consola(devtools) para testear:

   fetch("http://localhost:8080/", {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}),
    headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  }
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {console.log(data)})

desde ya muchas gracias
```

Comment: El header en el `fetch` no cumple ninguna función, lo puedes borrar. De lado del servidor intenta cambiar `origin: '*'` por `origin: true`

Comment: acabo de intentarlo y sigue hacienbdo lo mismo

Comment: lo que noto es que no hace una peticion OPTIONS antes de hacer el post como lo hace cuando hago un post con http de angular

Comment: Entonces incluye `app.options('*', cors())` antes de definir cualquier ruta